# Change file extensions in gradle

Tags: regex, groovy, gradle

This seems so simple, yet I cannot find a single source that provides a working solution.

I have a project like this:

```
src
 -main
  -resources
   -bpmns
    -nnn.bpmn
```

and I want gradle to rename all files that end with `bpmn` to `bpmn20.xml`, leaving all files that already have `bpmn20.xml` extensions untouched.

This is my approach:

```
task renameBPMN(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } //to pevent gradle from not executing this task
    from('src/main/resources/bpmn/')
    into('src/main/resources/bpmn/')
    rename ('/^.*\\.(bpmn)$/', '$1.bpmn20.xml')
}
```

According to some regex testers online, the regex should match `nnn.bpmn`, gradle however does nothing at all.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the gradle documentation, [`AbstractCopyTask::rename()`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:rename(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))'s regular expression does not need delimiters:

```
rename '(.*)_OEM_BLUE_(.*)', '$1$2'
```

---

Try replacing:

```
rename ('/^.*\\.(bpmn)$/', '$1.bpmn20.xml')
```

With:

```
rename ('^.*\\.(bpmn)$', '$1.bpmn20.xml')
```

Comment: that not what he asked. He said files ending with XXXbpnm to XXXbpnm20.xml (and excluding all other files including .xml in exclusion)

Comment: That's not the way I took it @ArunSangal..it sounded like OP wanted to change `.bpnm` files to `.bpnm20.xml`.  OP even said that their expression worked great in online testers, just didn't do anything in gradle.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your approach. Even if we take .bpmn files (extension ending) it didn't do what it was supposed to do. For ex: if there's 1.bpmn, 2.bpmn and 3.bpmn.xml files in a folder called bpmnfolder, then running your suggested line made all filesize 0 (blank) and Gradle created an extra file called "bpmn.bpmn20.xml" in bpmnfolder.

Comment: $ cat build.gradle
task renameBPMN(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } //to pevent gradle from not executing this task
    from('bpmnfolder')
    into('bpmnfolder')
    rename ('^.*\\.(bpmn)$', '$1.bpmn20.xml')
}

Comment: I +1'd your answer @ArunSangal. I haven't worked much with Gradle, but I quickly saw the mistake between his code/problem and Gradle's documentation. Thought that may have been it.

Comment: worked with one minor addition, in order to make $1 return the filename, i needed to put the parentheses like so: '(^.*)\\.(bpmn)$', thanks! (@Arun Sangal, the problem with bpmn.bpmn20.xml is caused by this)

Comment: agree. Glad you got it

Answer (score 2):

This is what he needs or actually this script would do it.

Here it'll change a file: filenamebpmn or filename.bpmn to filenamebpmn20.xml or filename.bpmn20.xml respectively. It'll ignore all other files whether it's a filenamebpmn.xml or filename.bpmn.xml or any other file.

**$ cat build.gradle**

```
task renameBPMN() << {

    fileTree("bpmnfolder").matching { include "*bpmn" }.each { fileName ->
      println "Will be changed to new name --- " + fileName
      file("${fileName}").renameTo("${fileName}20.xml")
    }
}
```

**$ ls -l bpmnfolder**

```
total 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:14 1bpmn
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 14:50 2bpmn
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 6 Aug  6 14:50 3bpmn.xml
```

**$ /cygdrive/c/gradle-2.0/bin/gradle renameBPMN**

```
:renameBPMN
Will be changed to new name --- C:\cygwin\home\c400093\giga\goga\giga\bpmnfolder\1bpmn
Will be changed to new name --- C:\cygwin\home\c400093\giga\goga\giga\bpmnfolder\2bpmn

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.153 secs
```

**$ ls -l bpmnfolder**

```
total 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:14 1bpmn20.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 14:50 2bpmn20.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 6 Aug  6 14:50 3bpmn.xml
```

**$**

**AND**

If you want to include filenames which end with bpmn as extension i.e. filename.bpmn or filenamebpmn, then use the following code.

**$ ls -l bpmnfolder**

```
total 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 1bpmn
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 2bpmn
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 6 Aug  6 15:39 3bpmn.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 8 Aug  6 15:39 4.bpmn
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 5.bpmn.xml
```

**$ cat build.gradle**

```
task renameBPMN() << {

    fileTree("bpmnfolder").matching { include "*bpmn" include "*.bpmn" }.each { fileName ->
      println "Will be changed to new name --- " + fileName
      file("${fileName}").renameTo("${fileName}20.xml")
    }
}
```

**$ /cygdrive/c/gradle-2.0/bin/gradle renameBPMN**

```
:renameBPMN
Will be changed to new name --- C:\cygwin\home\c400093\giga\goga\giga\bpmnfolder\1bpmn
Will be changed to new name --- C:\cygwin\home\c400093\giga\goga\giga\bpmnfolder\2bpmn
Will be changed to new name --- C:\cygwin\home\c400093\giga\goga\giga\bpmnfolder\4.bpmn

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.271 secs
```

**$ ls -l bpmnfolder**

```
total 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 1bpmn20.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 2bpmn20.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 6 Aug  6 15:39 3bpmn.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 8 Aug  6 15:39 4.bpmn20.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 c400093 Domain Users 3 Aug  6 15:39 5.bpmn.xml
```

**$**

Comment: thanks and +1 for your obvious effort, but Sam pointed me to the flaw with my code (backslashes not needed in gralde regex) so i ll pick his

Answer (score 1):

Modify your task to:

```
task rename(type: Copy) {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false } //to pevent gradle from not executing this task
    from('src/main/resources/bpmn/')
    into('src/main/resources/bpmn/')
    exclude { resource -> !resource.file.name.endsWith('.bpmn')}
    rename '(.*).bpmn', '$1.bpmn20.xml'
}
```

Comment: This would rename `src/main/resources/bpmn/example.notbpmn` to `src/main/resources/bpmn/example.no.bpmn20.xml` since `.` means any non-newline character: [***demo***](http://regex101.com/r/qL8sT5/1)

Comment: this code will change only the first of such file which ends with bpmn word.

Comment: This work for me, this code change the extension of all files with extension bpmn.

Comment: What version of Gradle. I'm 2.0. I tried your code on my machine, it didn't do any change to any file.